# How to unshelve changes into another branch using TFS?

Tags: tfs, tfvc

I am working on an application where I want to unshelve changes from one branch to another branch using TFS. I am attaching different images which contain my branches, shelve set name, and shelve set details. I want to unshelve changes at **05-PartnerIntergration** branch.

Shelve Set name is **Krone Integration**

Here are the branches shown below in image.

[image]

Comment: Hi, you could try using Team Foundation Server Power Tools and use the command:
tfpt unshelve /migrate /source:$/TeamProject/Main /target:$/TeamProject/Beta. You could refer to the blog: [Unshelving TFS changes into another branch (VS 2017) (yer.ac)](https://yer.ac/blog/2019/05/14/unshelving-tfs-changes-into-another-branch-vs-2017/#:~:text=tfpt%20unshelve%20%2Fmigrate%20%2Fsource%3A%22%24%2FCore%2FMyProduct%22%20%2Ftarget%3A%22%24Core%2FMyProduct-Branch%22%20%22MyShelveset%22%20In%20this,the%20source%20and%20target%20are%20named%20TFS%20folders.) for more details. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Multimerge 2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Jesusfan.MultiMerge2022) extension. [image: Image of an action: Unshelve to branch...]